# Finding Distinct Month

Tags: php, mysql

I make a page, that display records from database,in group of 10 records per page using paginition concept,

i wanna print Like: `Month name/Year`.

That month and year is distinct form that page means of 10 records.

Suppose page number 10 contains 10 records with 3 distinct month named `Dec 2011` , `Jan 2012`  and, `March 2012`,

In this case i want to print Month: Dec/2011 ,Jan,March/2012

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How is stored your date in database? Is it timestamp?

Comment: please paste your code and what the result you got.

Comment: no its not time time stamp, actualy this date is for Like Cheque date in form of YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

If your date is stored like you write it: Dec 2011, Jan 2012 then you should do like this

```
$arr = array();

$sql = mysql_query(__YOUR_SQL__);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $date = explode(" ", $row['date']);
    if(!array_key_exists($date[1], $arr))
        $arr[$date[1]] = array();
    array_push($arr[$date[1]], $date[0]);
}

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(count($value) == 1)
        echo $value[0] . '/' . $key;
    else
        echo implode(", ", $value) . ' ' . $key;
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir, but In database i have DATE field name and it's data type is also date so all the dates are stored in YYYY-MM-DD format and i wanna use only Month-YEAR means when suppose after your answer of i get distinct month then i want to prrint like e.g. Month: APRIL-2012 or e.g Month: DECEMBER-2012 & JAN-2012